# ADODB: Passing Array to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, adodb

My goal is to send 2 arrays ( one of integers and the other of strings )to a stored procedure which is on SQL 2k8.

I found many examples how to do this using SQL Types and ADO.NET, but unfortunately I have a very old project written in VC++6, which uses COM ADO.

One possible workaround is to combine these values somehow (as a single string: '15|2|35|78...') and then to parse this string on SQL Server side. But I'm worrying how faster would be that? Also I will have to check and make sure that the separator does not exist in some of the strings.

Other solution is to add the values directly to using ADODB::Recordset, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: See http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html. ADODB doesn't support table-valued parameters, which is better solution.